# ArrayList from server not being displayed on JSP

Tags: java, jsp, csv, servlets, arraylist

Making a web application that search and sorts through Arraylists that were made by loading the csv, reading the data and storing it in DAO. For some reason when im trying to test if the data can be retrieved and displayed on the JSP.

MajorImportersbycity.csv

```
"CITY-VILLE","COMPANY-ENTREPRISE","PROVINCE_ENG","PROVINCE_FRA","POSTAL_CODE-CODE_POSTAL","DATA_YEAR-ANNÉE_DES_DONNÉES"
"100 Mile House","BRAD PADDISON CONTRACTING LTD","British Columbia","Colombie-Britannique","V0K 2E0",2014
"100 Mile House","CENTRAL CHEVROLET GMC BUICK LTD.","British Columbia","Colombie-Britannique","V0K 2E0",2014
"100 Mile House","LONE BUTTE SUPPLY LTD.","British Columbia","Colombie-Britannique","V0K 2E0",2014
"100 Mile House","SARVAIR AVIATION LTD.","British Columbia","Colombie-Britannique","V0K 2E0",2014
"Abbotsford","4 SEASON KING MUSHROOMS LTD.","British Columbia","Colombie-Britannique","V4X 1C9",2014
"Abbotsford","A & P FRUIT GROWERS LTD.","British Columbia","Colombie-Britannique","V4X 2M4",2014
"Abbotsford","ABBOTSFORD CONCRETE PRODUCTS LIMITED PARTNERSHIP","British Columbia","Colombie-Britannique","V2S 7W8",2014
....
```

Listener.java:

```
public class Listener implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener {

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent context) {
    try {
        LoadCsvData.importersByCity();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

Listener calls LoadCsvData to load data from csv, parse it and store into global arraylist to be used as global arraylist(populated with the data from csv), LoadCsvData.java:

```
public class LoadCsvData {

public static ArrayList<Importer> importersByCanCity;  

public static ArrayList<Importer> getImportersByCanCity() {
    return importersByCanCity;
}

public static void setImportersByCanCity(ArrayList<Importer> importersByCity) {
    importersByCanCity = importersByCity;
}

public static ArrayList<HSCode> productHSCode;

public static void importersByCity() throws FileNotFoundException{

    try {
        ArrayList<Importer> importersByCity = new ArrayList<Importer>();
        String data;
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream url = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/MajorImportersbycity.csv");
        BufferedReader csv = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url));
        String line = csv.readLine();
        System.out.println("before while");
        while ((line = csv.readLine()) != null){
            String[] importer = line.split(",");
            String city = importer[0];
            String companyName = importer[1];
            String province_eng = importer[2];
            String province_fr = importer[3];
            String postal_code = importer[4];
            String year = importer[5].toString();
            Importer importers = new Importer(city, companyName, province_eng, province_fr, postal_code);
            if (importer != null) {
                //System.out.println(importer.toString() + "in while");
                importersByCity.add(importers);
            }
        }
        csv.close();
        System.out.println(importersByCity.size());
        setImportersByCanCity(importersByCity);

    } catch (IOException f ) {
        System.out.println("in catch clause");
        f.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Created a class that is used as a generic, to load the csv data into objects, Importer.java:

```
public class Importer {
private String city;
private String companyName;
private String province_eng;
private String province_fr;
private String postal_code;


public Importer(String city, String companyName, String province_eng, String province_fr, String postal_code) {
    this.city = city;
    this.companyName = companyName;
    this.province_eng = province_eng;
    this.province_fr = province_fr;
    this.postal_code = postal_code;
}
    public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

private void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}

private void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
}

public String getProvince_eng() {
    return province_eng;
}

private void setProvince_eng(String province_eng) {
    this.province_eng = province_eng;
}

public String getProvince_fr() {
    return province_fr;
}

private void setProvince_fr(String province_fr) {
    this.province_fr = province_fr;
}

public String getPostal_code() {
    return postal_code;
}

public void setPostal_code(String postal_code) {
    this.postal_code = postal_code;
}

@Override 
public String toString(){
    return "Importer [name =" + getCompanyName() + ", province=" + getProvince_eng() + " city=" + getCity() + " postal code=" + getPostal_code() + "]";
}


}
```

I created a test class to be a servlet to test if i can now use my loaded arraylist in my jsp, Test.java:

```
 public class Test extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

    try {
        System.out.println("gets to test servlet");
        List<Importer> beans = LoadCsvData.getImportersByCanCity();
        request.setAttribute("beans", beans);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        System.out.println(beans.size());

    } catch (Throwable theException) {
        System.out.println(theException);
    }
}
}
```

My jsp loads, but it only loads the table header. The table isnt populate with the data from the CSV, index.jsp:

```
<%@ page import="com.importersconnect.importersdata.Importer"
import="com.importersconnect.listener.LoadCsvData" language="java"
contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Importers Connect</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Importers List</h1>
<center>
    <table width="100 % " id='table1' border="1" cellspacing="2"
        cellpadding="2">
        <tr class="tab-highlighted-2">
            <td class="tab-highlighted-2" width="15">
                <div align="left">city</div>
            </td>
            <td class="tab-highlighted-2" width="20">
                <div align="left">companyName</div>
            </td>
            <td class="tab-highlighted-2" width="15">
                <div align="left">province_eng</div>
            </td>
            <td class="tab-highlighted-2" width="15">
                <div align="left">province_fr</div>
            </td>
            <td class="tab-highlighted-2" width="15">
                <div align="left">postal_code</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${beans}" var="view">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${view.city}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${view.companyName}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${view.province_eng}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${view.province_fr}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${view.postal_code}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>

</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>ImportConnect</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<listener>
<listener-class>com.importersconnect.listener.Listener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.importersconnect.sort.Test</servlet-class>
</servlet>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Where do you call `importersByCity()` to populate your list?

Comment: @PM77-1 in the listener class contextInitialized

Comment: Where is the output from the embedded debug print statements?  What do they show? There is no error handling for badly formatted CSV input and  any exception is being discarded, so seeing your console log is indispensable to debugging.  Also, we need to see the contents of the CSV file.  This question is not answerable in its present state.

Comment: @JimGarrison if you are referring to the importersByCity.size() call i made, that prints out the correct number of rows in the csv.

Comment: @PM77-1 He has shown it in web.xml

Comment: @JimGarrison : I noticed after posting my comment.

Comment: One possibility is that the Listener is being loaded by a different classloader than the one that loads the servlet, in which case they would have different instances of the class.  What servlet engine are you using?  This is a reason you should be using some kind of dependency injection (i.e. Spring) instead of depending on `public static` for linkage.

Comment: `index.jsp` is a *welcome-file*. It may be loaded before your servlet code runs.

Comment: @PM77-1 removed it, still doesn't work.

Comment: @JimGarrison I removed the clasdloader and used filereader with a hardcoded path still doesn't populate the table